# Apache 2.4 not loading php5.5 with Mac OS 10.8

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am trying to use Apache 2.4.7 with php5.5 in my Mini Mac with Mac Os 10.8.5

Apache 2.4.7 installed following instructions in [here](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/apache/)

Run apachectl -v, shows

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  4 2014 19:23:56
```

PHP5.5 installed following instructions in [here](http://ziad.eljammal.com/install-php-5-5-on-mac-os-x/)

Run php -v, shows

```
 PHP 5.5.8 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2014 18:50:29) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

I added in the apache http.conf file the following line

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

But it does not seem to work, as when I try to start the server with

```
sudo apachectl start
```

It produces the following error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 151 of /usr/local/apache-2.4.7/conf/httpd.conf:
    Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: 
        dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found:
            unixd_config\n
Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
Expected in: /usr/local/apache-2.4.7/bin/httpd in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so
```

As suggested in the tutorials I have linked, I modified my bash profile with

```
export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/apache/man:$MANPATH
```

I have been trying for hours different solutions, and this is as far as I got.

If someone can give me some hints I would be very happy, I am quite desperate...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours and hours of try this and do that, I managed to make it work.

I will describe what I did, in order to help other people save those hours!

**Be aware that this solution works for the MAc OS X 10.8.5.** It might not work for you!

The following is to have **apache 2.4.7** with **php 5.5** working

1. Update and download tools you need.

   1.1 - XCode. Get it from Apple Store for free.

   1.2 - XCode command line. Go to XCode, Preferences, Downloads, and get the command line.

   1.3 - Homebrew. Use the following command:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
   ```

   [See the website](http://brew.sh/) for more info.
2. Several checks

   2.1 - Check that there is no current apache or php instalation annoying around. To do so I deleted them and hunted down config files, just in case, with the commands

   ```
   find /usr -name "apache"

   find /usr -name "httpd"

   find /usr -name "php
   ```

   2.2 - Use brew doctor to confirm no configs are annoying the setup.

   ```
   brew doctor
   ```

   2.3 - Check that you did it right by confirming that following commands **do not work**

   ```
   php -v
   apachectl -v
   httpd -v
   ```
3. Install apache

   3.1 - Use the [homebrew apache2 from djl](https://github.com/djl/homebrew-apache2).

   ```
   brew tap djl/homebrew-apache2
   brew install djl/apache2/apache24
   ```

   3.2 - Modify your .bash_profile in order to make the /usr/local/bin the priority folder (so the system gets the apache and php from there instead other folder like /usr/sbin)

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   3.3 - Confirm that apache works. To do this, start the service and go to localhost where "It works" appears. Then shut it down to proceed with php.

   ```
   sudo apachectl start
   (Go to browser and open localhost)
   sudo apachectl stop
   ```
4. Install php

   4.1 Use the [homebrew php from josegonzalez](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php)

   ```
   brew tap homebrew/dupes
   brew tap homebrew/versions
   brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
   brew install php55
   ```

   4.2 In case **it did not work** because of the following error :

   ```
   cannot open /usr/share/httpd/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/apxs line 217.
   ```

   ... create a symlink this way:

   ```
   cd /usr/share/
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/apache24/< apache version installed >/ httpd
   ```

   ...  and execute the install again.

   < apache version installed > will depend on the version installed. 
   At the moment of this writing, it is 2.4.10
5. Tell Apache about its new friend.

   5.1 Modify the httpd.conf.
   First open the file.

   ```
   cd /usr/local/etc/apache2/
   sudo nano httpd.conf
   ```

   ... then add the php module in the LoadModule section (search for LoadModule)

   ```
   LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
   ```

   ... and add the php type in the mime_module. Search for mime_module and, in that section, search for # Filters

   ... add the next line under them.

   ```
   # process php type files using apache php module
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   ```

   that tells Apache to run the file through it's php processor prior to sending it to the client.

   ... save and exit.
6. OPTIONAL, if you want to store the Sites in your User folder instead of WebService.

   6.1 Modify again the httpd.conf.
   Open the file.

   ```
   cd /usr/local/etc/apache2/
   sudo nano httpd.conf
   ```

   And add the following lines **at the end of the file**, replacing  with your username.

   ```
   ServerName dev.local
   User <username>
   Group staff

   DocumentRoot "/Users/<username>/Sites"
   ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache-error.log"
   CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/apache-access.log" common
   <Directory "/Users/<username>/Sites">
     Options All
     AllowOverride All
     IndexOptions NameWidth=*

     Require all denied
     Require host localhost
     Require host 127.0.0.1
   </Directory>
   ```
7. Finish it!

   7.1 Start apache service

   ```
   sudo apachectl start
   ```

   7.2 Create a php file in the root of your Sites folder (If you did step 6, create it in /Users//Sites/test.php)

   7.3 Open it.

   ```
   Go to Browser and localhost/test.php
   ```

Good luck.

Comment: we have felt your same frustration. we tried the same thing as you, and failing, decided to try Brew. Brew complained MacPorts was still installed, "which port" in t showed us where to trash that file. ready to brew... next error: compile failed. We needed to copy apsx from /usr/local/apache/bin to /usr/sbin, then brew finished install & make. but no php parsing. at first the MIME thing didn't make sense, as we thought that related to files being sent to a browser (i.e. send mp3 opens mp3 player on computer), but after fol your directions, php was parsed. we edited that section to help too! tu

Comment: I'm glad it helped! And contributions are welcome of course. Hope it helps other people too.

Comment: I don't really understant step 4.2, I should add a simlink from the folder which contains `config_vars.mk` to the httpd's folder binary or to the apxs one's?

Comment: To the apache's folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are experiencing `the zend_parse_paramater` error from apache2, while loading libphp5.so:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 151 of /usr/local/apache-2.4.7/conf/httpd.conf:
    Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: 
        dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found:
```

take a look at the ./configure output. if you get a message saying something similar to:

configure: warning: bison versions supported for regeneration of the Zend/PHP parsers: 1.28 1.35 1.75 1.875 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.4.1 (found: none).

try installing bison: sudo apt-get install bison

then make distclean then ./configure ... then make -i install

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly it did not fix the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 0):

This guide is great, except for the step 4.1, where you have to install php like this:

```
brew install php55 --homebrew-apxs
```

this line will put the "LoadModule php5_module …" automatically in the httpd.conf, so if somebody made the others steps above, just remove php with:

```
brew remove php55
```

and then install php with the line:

```
brew install php55 --homebrew-apxs
```

and then there's no problem anymore!

Comment: This will make step 5 unnecessary indeed. Nice contribution to the answer - not an answer by itself though